# Equivalence classes under logical equivalence by 13 valuations

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, equivalence-relations

Let L be the set of 5 propositional variables. 
Under the equivalence relation given by logical equivalence, how many equivalence classes of propositional terms are given the value TRUE by 13 valuations on L?

Comment: There are $2^5=32$ rows in a truth table for the term. How many ways are there to select $13$ of the rows to have TRUE in the output column?

Answer (score 0):

so if there are 32 rows in a truth table, do I have to do 32C13 to find the number of ways there are to select 13 rows to have the True output column?